# Prevent registerField from clearing the widget

Tags: python, pyqt5

I am using `registerField` with a `QLineEdit` widget of `Page2` in sample code below.

When I enter some text in `QLineEdit` of `Page2` and come back to `Page1`, then on going on back to `Page2` the `QLineEdit` field is cleared.

If I comment `registerField` line it doesn't.

How do I prevent `self.lineedit` from getting cleared while using `registerField`

Sample Code

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets

class TestWizard(QtWidgets.QWizard):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(TestWizard, self).__init__(parent)
        self.addPage(Page1(self))
        self.addPage(Page2(self))
        self.finished.connect(self.onFinished)
    
    def onFinished(self):
        print(self.field('entry'))
        
class Page1(QtWidgets.QWizardPage):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Page1, self).__init__(parent)
        self.comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.comboBox)
        self.setLayout(layout)


class Page2(QtWidgets.QWizardPage):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Page2, self).__init__(parent)
        self.lineedit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.lineedit)
        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.registerField('entry',self.lineedit) # Commenting this line prevents self.lineedit from clearing

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    t = TestWizard()
    t.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution is to override the cleanupPage method that just cleans the fields:

```py
class Page2(QtWidgets.QWizardPage):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Page2, self).__init__(parent)
        self.lineedit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.lineedit)
        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.registerField("entry", self.lineedit)

    def cleanupPage(self):
        pass
```

Comment: Thanks. It is working. One doubt  - cleanupPage() is called when the user leaves the page by clicking Back. So why is the field not getting cleared when registerField is not used?

Comment: @inxp Precisely for this reason, the implementation of cleanupPage is to reset the fields to the default value, if it is not a field then it will not be reset

Comment: Got it. Thanks :)